# Error: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when running setup.py file

Tags: python, macos, ssl, pip, python-3.8

**OS:** `MacOS Monterey 12.5.1`

**Python version:** `3.8`

*Tried to RUN:*
`python setup.py sdist upload -r local`

*Got the following error:*

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)>
error: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)>
```

Comment: Don't put "& the solution" in your question title. _Every_ question that shows a nonzero number of answers available has a (proposed) solution, so it's redundant. Also, after the timeout lets you click the checkbox next to your answer it'll format as being solved, so again, the extra verbiage is unnecessary.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with Jfrog repository. I used twine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**The Fix:**

*Run the following command:*

```
pip install certifi
/Applications/Python\ 3.8/Install\ Certificates.command
```